# Как получить изменненый массив данных?

Tags: javascript

```
let ticketArr = []
   
   //Пушу значения в масив 
   const pushToBucket = player  => {
         ticketArr.push(player)
         console.log('Updated ticketArr' , ticketArr) //здесь выводит обновленый массив
   }
  
  
   //нужно вывести новое значение ticketArr в console.log() , по задумке в масив будут приходить данные по клику пользователя
   console.log(ticketArr)    //Выведет пустой масив , а нужно вывести масив с новыми данными
```

Comment: Вы не полный код привели. Последняя строчка выведет пустой массив, потому что вы нигде не вызвали функцию pushToBucket. В текущем виде не понятно в чём конкретно проблема.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev функция pushToBucket висит на кнопке , которою нажимает пользователь .Могу дать ссылку на песочницу (https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-framework-fgb5f?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @PavelGrishaev там еще в чем штука , я получаю в отдельный массив данные того столбика напротив которого была нажата кнопка "+" 

Моя задача отрисовать/ зарендерить инфу с нового массива в елемент корзина(то что слева выезжает)

Если можете помочь буду очеень признателен.

Comment: Не надо ссылок,  нам и так все ясно. Если `pushToBucket` вызывается по нажатию на кнопку, то не следует ожидать, что `ticketArr` будет содержать элементы **ДО** нажатия на кнопку.

Comment: @Igor как поступить тогда? Чтобы это все подгружалось

Answer (score 0):

Ваш последний console.log(ticketArr) выводит пустой массив так как вызывается сразу при запуске кода. Поместите его в функцию и вызывайте тогда когда массив уже будет обновлён.

```js
let ticketArr = []
   
const pushToBucket = player  => {
  ticketArr.push(player)
  logArray();
}
  
function logArray(){
    console.log(ticketArr) ;
}

pushToBucket('pl1');
pushToBucket('pl2');
pushToBucket('pl3');
```

Comment: спасибо, я попробую но уже завтра (

Answer (score 0):

```js
let ticketArr = []
   
const pushToBucket = player  => {
     ticketArr.push(player)     
}
  
pushToBucket(5);  
pushToBucket(10);  
pushToBucket(15);  

   
console.log('Updated ticketArr' , ticketArr)
```